# Display comment regarding posts

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am developing a blog using codeigniter, every thing works good like posts are being stored comments are being made likes also works the only problem is fetching the comments using codeigniter against each post. What i want to do is that i want to send id to controller of each id when page loads. Here is the screenshot to make it more clear how i am working.
[Front end is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4px1.png)

Now the code section:

**1. Code on the blog page where all messages and posts are being shown**

```
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9 post_message" id="getComments<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>">
                    <p> 
                        <?php echo $blog -> message; ?> 
                    </p>
                    <span class="pull-left"> 
                        <small> Posted By: <?php echo $blog -> name; ?></small> 
                    </span>
<!--                    onclick="get_comments(this.id, '<?php //echo base_url('users/get_comments_total'); ?>')" id="<?php// echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>-->
                    <a> 
                        <i class='fa fa-comment' aria-hidden='true'></i> Comments (<small> <?php echo $rows; ?> </small>)
                    </a>
                    <a onclick="update_like('<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>', '<?php echo base_url('users/update_like'); ?>')">
                        <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up' aria-hidden='true'></i> Likes (<small><?php echo $blog -> likes; ?></small>)
                    </a>
                    <div class="result_id<?php echo $blog -> blog_id; ?>" style="display: block;float: left;width: 100%;"></div>
                </div> <!-- End of post message -->
```

In the above code there is a line written in comments where on-click function is defined i want to pass each id on page load to controller instead of click and all this code is written in **foreach** loop.

Help me with this thing or tell if there is any better idea to achieve this. Please do see the image attached with this so that you can know easily how i want to display the comments. one hint is like FB comments.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$rows`?

If the likes are working OK then you can use the same idea for the comments. Probably you have joined the likes table and that is why you have `$blog -> likes;`. You should join the comments table to the query and then use `Comments (<small> <?php echo $blog->comments; ?> </small>)`.

If this does not work you should provide your query in the model and your database structure.